# Java task solving using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to code a solution to a question related to arrays in Java.   The question goes like this:

> You are given an array of length *n*, indexed from 0 to *n* - 1. Each element of the array is either 0 or 1. You can only move to an index which contains 0. At first you are at the 0<sup>th</sup> position. In each move you can do one of the following things:
>
> - Walk one step forward or backward.
> - Make a jump of exactly length *m* forward.
>
> That means you can move from position *x* to *x* + 1, *x* - 1 or *x* + *m* in one move. The new position must contain 0. Also you can move to any position greater than n-1.
>
> You can't move backward from position 0. *If you move to any position greater than n - 1, you win the game.*
>
> Given the array and the length of the jump, you need to determine if it's possible to win the game or not.
>
> Here are the example test cases:
>
> ```
> 6 5  
> 0 0 0 1 1 1  
> YES  
> 6 3  
> 0 0 1 1 1 0  
> NO
> ```

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class hcrkarryjump {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            a[k]=sc.nextInt();
        int i=0;
        while(i<n){
            if(a[i]==0)
                i++;
            if(a[i]==1){
                if(a[i+1]==0 &&(i+m>=n-1))
                    System.out.println("YES");
                else
                    System.out.println("NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code goes into an infinite loop and please do correct me if there are any errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: @ochi:  I think the question reads fine; the problem is that there's an infinite loop.  It's also clear to see where the infinite loop is occurring.

Comment: _"That means you can move from position to , or in one move"_ -- Why did you omit the critical information? Position WHAT to WHAT "in one move"?

Comment: if you get to a[i]==1 you never increment anymore, that's why you have an infinite loop.

Comment: FYI: This is the HackerRank challenge [Java 1D Array (Part 2)](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-1d-array)

Comment: yes. its from hackerrank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an infinite loop because you never increment once you get to a[i] == 1.

To avoid the infinite loop, your code should be :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class hcrkarryjump {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            a[k]=sc.nextInt();
        int i=0;
        while(i<n){
            // Check if we have something to do
            if(a[i]==1){
                // We do stuff
                if(a[i+1]==0 &&(i+m>=n-1))
                    System.out.println("YES");
                else
                    System.out.println("NO");
            }
            // and increment for the while check and next loop
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the rules as written so can't say for sure "this is right" or "this is wrong". I will point out however (just in case it *was* unintentional) that as you've written the code, you are now incrementing `i` twice if `a[i]==0` is `true`.

Comment: Yup I thought about removing the if(a[i]==0) i++; all together but I thought that it might be there to avoid one extra loop and since it does nothing but increment once it doesnt hurt the code.

Comment: One other thing of note, `a[i+1]` will throw an exception if i+1 = n.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder Rules are pretty simple. Get to the end, stepping only on `0` values. You can walk +1, -1, or +N, where N is the second number given, e.g. `5` in the first example.

Comment: @TheBakker Your first line correctly identifies the error in the code. However, the challenge posed in the question is a lot more complex that your suggested solutions. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37556681/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas Yeah. Just saw your answer and cleared things right up. :)

Comment: Indeed, I only corrected the infinite loop issue, because that blocked him from going forward. 
 
Giving the full solution might not be the best course of action as he won't get to push and find the solution himself.

Comment: Which is why I didn't even try to give a solution (which I had already solved on [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-1d-array), so I recognized it), but instead pointed out, *with examples*, that the current algorithm will not be able to work, because it requires backtracking logic.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever land on a case where a[i] != 0 (therefor it is 1), you'll finish the iteration, but you don't add something to your variable i.

So eg:

```
Take 1 step i => 1
Land on 0, ok i => 2
Land on 1, print yes or no, i=> 2
Land on the same 1, print ... , i => 2
```

Therefor the condition while( i < n ) is constantly true.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you never increment `i` once `a[i] == 1`. It'll just sit there spinning on the same position (`i` value).

However, your algorithm is flawed. Consider this case:

```
8 3
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
↑                  start position
      ↑            forward 3 (couldn't forward 1 or backward 1)
    ↑              backward 1 (couldn't forward 1 or 3)
          ↑        forward 3 (couldn't backward 1 and already been to forward 1)
                ↑  forward 3 (couldn't forward 1 or backward 1)  WIN !!!
```

You don't check all 3 options (backward 1, forward 1, forward X).

You also don't check if you've already been somewhere. Without checking if you've been somewhere, your code may end up looping: *forward 1, backward 1, forward 1, backward 1, forward 1, backward 1, forward 1, backward 1, and so on...*

Now consider this one:

```
16 5
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
↑                                    start position
          ↑                          forward 5
                    ↑                forward 5
                  ↑                  backward 1  DEAD END !!! (or loop if not checking "been there")
↑                                    backtrack to here
  ↑                                  forward 1
    ↑                                forward 1
              ↑                      forward 5
                        ↑            forward 5
                                  ↑  forward 5  WIN !!!
```

As you can see, you may need to backtrack to find the correct path. This is true regardless of which of the 3 options (backward 1, forward 1, forward X) you try first.

Backtracking logic like that is most often implemented using a recursive method, but can also be done by manually maintaining a stack.

Finally, you should only print `YES` or `NO` when you've completed your search, i.e. if you get to the end, print `YES`and stop the search, or if you've tried all combinations without getting to the end, print `NO`.